# ERROR! It looks like your version of the NDK does not support API level

Tags: android, android-ndk, rubymotion

I've followed the instructions given at http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/getting-started but when I get to the instruction `Rake device` I get the error:

`ERROR! It looks like your version of the NDK does not support API level . Switch to a lower API level or install a more recent NDK.`

It seems when other people get this error they're given an API level (level L seems to be a popular problem causer).

I've tried with a few different versions of NDK (9d, 10, 10b) and SDK (19, 20, L) but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply uninstalled all the Android L stuff from my "Android SDK Manager" entirely. Worked after that.

*(I might have had to remove Android 20 as well -- not near my Android development Mac atm)*

Answer (score 0):

The blank API level in the error message looks like android-L, certainly he doesn't find it in NDK r10b since it's only part of the 64bit-host/64bit-target NDK package.

But unless you want to target devices that are using Android-L or higher, you shouldn't use the NDK platform android-L.

I don't know how Rubymotion works, but with standard use of the NDK, you should put `APP_PLATFORM:=android-15` (where 15 would be your minimum supported SDK level) inside `Application.mk`. Maybe there is similar setting you can tweak in Rubymotion's configuration ?